# What does dummy_threading do?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

When would I use `dummy_threading`?

I had thought it might replace system-level threads with mock threads in case system-level threads weren't available for Python.

But when I run this:

```
import dummy_threading as threading

semaphore = threading.Semaphore()
def f(i):
    semaphore.acquire()
    print i
for i in xrange(10):
    threading.Thread(target=f, args=(i,)).start()
for _ in xrange(10):
    semaphore.release()
```

I get `0`, and the program doesn't terminate. Not only that, but Python inexplicably continues to chew up my computer's memory until it has nothing left.

When I run this:

```
import threading

semaphore = threading.Semaphore()
def f(i):
    semaphore.acquire()
    print i
for i in xrange(10):
    threading.Thread(target=f, args=(i,)).start()
for _ in xrange(10):
    semaphore.release()
```

I get `0 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8` as expected.

I must misunderstand `dummy_threading`. When would I use it?

FYI, I tried this on Windows 7 and Fedora 18 for comparison and got the same results.

EDIT: The following, however, gives `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`:

```
import dummy_threading as threading

event = threading.Event()
def f(i):
    event.wait()
    print i
for i in xrange(10):
    threading.Thread(target=f, args=(i,)).start()
event.set()
```

The big question is: what does `dummy_threading` *do*, or alternatively when would it give the same behavior as `threading`?

Answer (score 5):

The module is meant to be used when `thread` and `threading` are not available on your platform.

The functions you pass to it are called *synchronously*, and you called `.start()` immediately. The first function acquires the semphore, prints, then the second function is called and blocks. It is run synchronously and never returns.

From the [`dummy_thread` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dummy_threading.html):

> Be careful to not use this module where deadlock might occur from a thread being created that blocks waiting for another thread to be created. This often occurs with blocking I/O.

and from an [EFF-bot post](http://effbot.org/librarybook/dummy-threading.htm) (otherwise short and missing a working link):

> Helpers to make it easier to write code that use threads where supported, but still runs on Python versions without thread support. The dummy modules simply run the threads sequentially.

Note the *making it easier* part; without actual threads, you cannot expect code run under `dummy_threading` to not deadlock in the manner that it does in your example.

Comment: Does `dummy_threading` intend to give similar results? Because doesn't seem to work, as per my example.

Comment: @PaulDraper: it is intended to make the API look the same, without actually implementing threads.

Answer (score 4):

In `dummy_threading`, thread are just function wrappers, they are executed sequentially.

The problem with the second snippet is that `dummy_threading.Thread.start()` does not return until the corresponding `f` call exits. Thread `0` will acquire the semaphore, then thread `1` will attempt to acquire it and block. And nothing will ever release the semaphore because there's only one thread which is blocked.

UPDATE: Made some research about dummy events behaviour.

In fact, all of `Semaphore`, `Event`, `Condition` etc in `dummy_threading` are exactly the same as for normal `threading` with the exception that they're using dummy locks (there's some importing magic done for this.) As a result, when you call `event.wait()`, the underlying lock never blocks the thread. Neither blocks the lock used by `Semaphore`, but internally semaphore loops until the resource is available:

```
 while self.__value == 0:  # Here it will loop forever
    if not blocking:
        break
    ....
    self.__cond.wait()
```

I think, that dummy events violate the assumption that whenever `wait` called without arguments returns, it means that the event was set, but not sure if that can be helped easily.

Comment: If I replace the `Semaphore` with an `Event` it works, but I would imagine that should fail for the same reason, no?

Comment: @PaulDraper apparently, there's some pecularity in dummy `Event`, it's `wait` never blocks even if it's not set (in that case it returns `False`, which is compliant with the API). I think, that differs for `Semaphore` because it has an explicit way of a non-blocking `acquire`.

Comment: Is that peculiarity on in `dummy_threading`? Because the `threading` API description is: "Block until the internal flag is true. If the internal flag is true on entry, return immediately. Otherwise, block until another thread calls set() to set the flag to true, or until the optional timeout occurs."